# Run `node server` command in Ubuntu 18 on startup and reboot

Tags: node.js, pm2, adapt

I've installed the Adapt Authoring tool on an AWS Ubuntu 18 instance. It is started up with a `node server` command. I've looked into pm2 and some other solutions. I can start the process using `pm2 start 'node server'`, but pm2 does not list the process so I can't save it... I've also looked at upstart, which seems possibly outdated. I tried to add a process using update-rc.d to no effect. I also tried adding a service to `/etc/systemd/system/`. No go. None of these solutions seem to work with this startup command.

What is the solution I am supposed to be using for this?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like pm2 will work, but it needs to be run like so: `pm2 start 'node server'`. Then it will run, list, and save the process.

Comment: ..and then `pm2 startup`